# Accessing an image file in an asset pack from angular html ionic app

Tags: angular, android-image, android-assets

I figured out how to build a separate large **asset pack** for placing 300MB of images.

What I don't understand is how to reference those images from my Angular typescript Ionic app.

when the images were in `src/assets/myImages` (**not** an asset pack) the url in the page was simply `assets/myImages/xyz.jpg`

The **asset pack** has files in `/assets/myImages/*` but apparently they aren't really dumped into the same assets directory (or virtually accessed as if they were in the same app assets directory.

What does the URL look like to access the files now that they are in an **asset pack**?
Is there just a longer path I can use in the URL path reference?

Do I need to jump through some JS (or Java?) API to get the asset pack root dir reference?
If so, what is that API?